# How to create a `typedef`/type alias in Eclipse Papyrus for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I am using the `Papyrus` UML plugin with Eclipse Neon to design a C++ library. I want to create a `typedef` to alias some complicated types, but I could not figure out how to do this.

I added the `AnsiCLibrary` package for the standard C types, which is fine. I tried to use the `PrimitiveType` node from the palette, but that did not work--it created a `struct` instead of a `typedef`.

I am trying to add the following typedefs:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrixRowToConvertToPointsType;

typedef unsigned long maximumDimension;
```

It seems like I have to add a typedef to a ModelLibrary package--like the `AnsiCLibrary`, but I could not find a way to do that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont know papyrus, so really just asking out of curiousity: You want to have the names in your UML diagrams different from the real names?

Comment: FYI, there are no standard C/C++ types because C++ has `std::string` and `std::vector` and C doesn't.

Comment: Please edit your post with your attempt at the `typedef`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks for the note. I added the example typedefs as asked.

Comment: @tobi303 Not exactly. So I want to create a name alias for a complicated data type. That way, I don't have to keep writing out a long data type each time--room for bugs, etc. So in a class I want to create an attribute that takes a specific aliased data type. That is all. I don't want to change the names of the UML diagrams themselves.

Comment: Hi, if look for the word "alias" in the UML document, it is used to alias type imported from others namespaces. It is defined in NamedElement which is one the root classes of the abstract syntax. But I am not sure that maps to your question. See "NamedElement may have both a name and a nameExpression associated with it. In this case, the name can be used as an
alias for the NamedElement, which may be used, for example, in referencing the element in a Constraint expression.". Otherwise I am not sure that there is an UML element which models an alias.